# SSIS or replication for copying parts of a database to the same server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I have a client who has been promised that he will get a regular copy of the database behind the application we are hosting for him.

The copy is in fact a backup (DB_EXPORT.BAK) that he downloads through SFTP.

(I know, I did not make that promise). I do not want to give him the whole  with all the proprietary stored procedures, functions, users and other stuff. I want to give him a slimmed down version of that database with most tables, only selected sp's, some functions, no users and so on.
As I see there are two ways to do this:

1. a SSIS job that copies certain stuff (using Import/Export Wizard)
2. replication (snapshot or transactional)

The thing is: the original (DB1) AND the copy (DB_EXPORT) will be hosted on the same server. So using replication feels a bit awkward (publishing to yourself?) but it does give an easy interface for configuring which articles to replicate. Using a SSIS package feels more logical but is actually hard to change.

What can you say about this? Is there a better way for doing this? I am looking for a way that will allow people who just about understand SQL server wil be able to understand.

Thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: What about a 2nd database with a view pointed at the source tables (filtered by whatever criteria you use).  Then you can just grant access to the 2nd db without even copying the data.  You would need to create new procedures/functions in the 2nd db, but you save on storage.  Careful with permissions if you go this route as the user needs read access to original db tables.

Comment: Well, the copy will be backupped and shipped to the client, so that is not a possible route.

Comment: Got it.  I do not believe you can filter rows in a snapshot, so you'd have to do transnational replication to get row filtering.  But if this is an SFTP grab, you likely don't need this database up-to-date 24/7 - so then do you want to incur the overhead of replication?  If you're not keen on SSIS, you could write (assuming you're on SQL2005+) a simple stored proc that you run on schedule to merge data into your destination from the source, then call a backup job once the merge is done.  That would be my vote I believe.

Comment: Yes, the database should be updated once every 24hrs. A 'shorter' schedule would be appreciated by the client but not enough to pay for ;) This machine is on SQL 2008R2. I agree on the proc but I have some colleagues that are not very proficient in writing T-SQL. They should be able to maintain/adapt/repair what I create. That is the most complicating factor in this I believe ;) There needs to be no row filtering. A table is added as a whole or not. I am most concerned about the functions and procs that contain application logic.

Comment: If you're basically providing your client with an exact copy (and you don't need the copy online), why not just schedule your nightly backup jobs to create two .bak files, one of which is accessible via SFTP by your client?  If you need to remove certain tables, then I'd think snapshot replication is the way to go in this case (avoiding TSQL scripts), and once the snapshot job is created, alter it to run a backup to your SFTP folder after the new snapshot is created.

Comment: @JiggsJedi I guess recplication it is..... Can you mark that as an answer so I can give you your earned credits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best answer, but I would go with snapshot replication per our discussion, and your avoidance of TSQL scripting.

Replication is relatively simple to setup, but can be a nightmare to troubleshoot (esp. transactional).  Often times, its easier to completely delete the publication/subscription and rebuild.

On that note, you can fully script replication configurations -- if someone else has to maintain this, it may be as simple as you scripting out the replication removal (pub and sub removal), and scripting out the replication build-out.  All they'd have to do is run the drop/build scripts and it's done.

You can also alter the scheduled job to run the backup immediately following the snapshot generation.

Comment: Good tips @jiggsjedi, especially adapting the scheduled job! There was now a separate job for backing it up to disk, one less job to schedule and worry about ;)